# add animation to one of the images in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

I am implementing one dashboard.in this dashboard 3 images at the loading time are uploaded and then using jQuery which I attached to my question, one by one fadeOut and FadeIn.when I arrive to the last image ,the task  will be finished.but now my PM asked me , when I arrive to the last , only the last image moves horizontaly in the background and not remaine fixed.how can I apply animation to one of images(the last one) in my Div?
now with this jQuery function I do a little but there is one bug that it is not circular.who can give me a suggestion?

i want to have somthing like that in my background: but only for the last image not all of them:
http://user.augmented-reality.it/X10Y/POC-WebGLViewer/
I tested this solution but did not work for me.

http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-background-animation/

```js
function raiseToSunrise(interval){
  var num = 1;
  var theinterval = setInterval(function() {

    var $active = $('#layout .active');
    //var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#layout img:first');
    var $next = $active.next();
    $next.css('z-index',1);//move the next image up the pile

    $active.fadeOut(8000,function(){//fade out the top image
      $active.css('z-index',0).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',2).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one      
    });
    console.log('num ==',num);
    if(num==3){
        console.log('I am in');
         $next.delay(13000);
         var circileInterval=setInterval(function(){
          $next.animate({right: "+=1000"}, 20000);
        },circileInterval);
       
      }
    num = num+1;
    if(num == 4){      
      clearInterval(theinterval);
    }
  }, interval)

};
```

```css
#layout {
  z-index:-1;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;         
}

#layout img {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index:0;        
}

#layout .active {
  z-index:2;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout" class="active">
  <img class="active" src="assets/css/images/img_background_night1.jpg"></img>
  <img  src="assets/css/images/img_background_sunrise1.jpg"></img>
  <img  src="assets/css/images/img_background_day1.jpg" ></img>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no background image on a `img` element to animate. Use `div` instead.

Comment: and then what can I do with fadeOut jQuery function? because as you see I am fadingOut each image using jQuery function, if I add one div above the last img , as you say, maybe jQuery function (raiseToSunrise) doet not apply on the my last image, am I right?

Comment: Replace `img` with `div` and add the images as `style="background-image:url(image.jpg);"`

Comment: but, is there possibility in CSS to add three urls? if so, how can I manage the fadeIn fdeOut of these background images?

Comment: Yes you can add the urls in the css and you can fade them with `opacity: 1` in your `.active` class

Answer (score 0):

Remove `class="day"` from third one, may be its help..

Comment: No for sure It does not help.It was in this way before and nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

I did fadeOut using jQuery function. But then I added one background image using repeat-x property.

So in this way I have 3 images which faded out one by one. When finished we have one image (same as the third image) that is repeating in the background.

```js
function raiseToSunrise(interval){
  var num = 1;
  var i=0;
  var $next;
  var $active;
  var initialRight;

  $active = $('#layout .active');
  var theinterval = setInterval(function() {
  for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    //var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#layout img:first');
     $next = $active.next();
    $next.css('z-index',1);//move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(8000,function(){//fade out the top image
     $active.css('z-index',0).removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',2).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one  

    });
      $active=$next;   
      }
      $active.fadeOut(8000,function(){//fade out the top image
     $active.css('z-index',0).removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the imag  
     
    }); 
  
      clearInterval(theinterval);
   // }
  }, theinterval)
};
```